# Teradata RegExp_Split_To_Table Error on TD

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

Not the nest at coding

```
with t as
 (
   select MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID as id, 
      Cast(Note as VARCHAR(100)) as Note, 
      UPDATEDAT,
      Cast(MHK_TYPE  as VARCHAR(100)) as MHK_TYPE
   from vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Notes
   Where cast(UPDATEDAT as Date) >= '2021/08/15'
 ) --- pull table

select MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID, MHK_Type, UpdateAt, Note, 
   regexp_substr(Token, '.*<b>*\K.*'),
   dt.*-- trim everything up to '<b>' 
FROM TABLE
 ( RegExp_Split_To_Table(t.id, t.Note,'<b>|<\/b>|<BR>|</BR>*', 'i')     -- split whenever '<\/b>' occurs
   RETURNS ( MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID BIGINT,
             TokenNum INT,
             Token VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET Unicode,
             MHK_TYPE VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET Unicode, 
             UPDATEDAT Date)
           ) AS dt
```

Teradata exception: [Teradata Database] [9881]
Function 'RegExp_Split_To_Table' called with an invalid number or type of parameters

Trying to figure out why i am getting this message as im going between RegExp and RegSplit
Field has mostly alot of data in it most split with ~ etc. but try to pull out sections of it is always a challenge especially when end user have free reign to do whatever.

Comment: RegExp_Split_to_Table returns 3 columns, to get MHK_TYPE & UPDATEDAT you must join the result back to vcoreMEDHOK_MHK_Notes.

Comment: To avoid the join you might also try to concat MHKAPPEALSINTERNALID, MHK_TYPE & UPDATEDAT into a single VarChar column and use this as id. And then apply STRTOK to split it back into 3 columns.

Comment: @dnoeth great suggestions.

Comment: You are passing too many arguments. It should be `regexp_split_to_table (<source string>,<regex>,<match argument>)`.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the `>*` within the regexp patterns. Do you really mean match zero or more `>` characters? Or should the preceding expression be in parentheses followed by a `+`?

Comment: Thank you !!Andrew & @Fred